# Dual-boot (Win7/13.04) won't boot to Windows (no grub menu). Boot-repair didn't fix it

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu using this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xK8X7_tYWmA
But it doesn't show the grub menu when I startup, it only boots into Ubuntu. I can look in my hard drive via the File manager and clearly see Windows is still installed, so I didn't accidently install Ubuntu over it or anything. I read on many forums that installing and running boot-repair from the Live-CD would solve the problem, but it didn't. I ran it twice, so I have two URLS:
paste.ubuntu.com/6023342
paste.ubuntu.com/6023353

Can anyone help me? I'm desperate to be able to log back into Windows. I've seen a few threads saying that their install will only boot into Windows, but no one with my problem of only booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `fdisk -l` and `mount`?

Comment: This question is irreproducible because the OP hasn't signed on in over 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

I broke my Windows 7 by doing some bad formatting.

What you should do first is minimize the damage. If you are still able to boot from Ubuntu. Google search for recovery software for the Ubuntu OS. And try to copy the files form Windows into Ubuntu.
You might actually be able to access the FILES from your WINDOWS partition via Ubuntu. - Try and look into the Local Disk via Ubuntu.

My point is that you can (almost) always format the computer. But you wont always be able to get your personal files back. So before you start tinkering. Try and recover some files you do not want to loose.

Comment: Oh, I can see the files from my Windows partition. And I did back-up most of my files and the rest I can easily do. But I'd really like to get this dual-boot to work, and if I can avoid formatting, I'd like to. But at the same time, I do need Windows to work asap... =\

Comment: Well.. There are ways to get windows without having a CD.. but I wont talk about that here :x ... 
I got windows 8 after my fifth failed Ubuntu installation (My Hardware is not compatible) It is totally up to you, but grub is scary for beginners like me. If you have Ubuntu Working, and Have saved your files (Do it on an extern Harddisk please) Then why not format Re-install the Windows Partition?
The video you have linked also shows the Uploaders comment: 
"I recently uploaded a dulboot using the option along side windows. try using that method it should work"
So try and check his new Video!